# Oracle shows 701 weird table instead of default ones

Tags: sql, oracle

I just installed OracleDB10 because we use it in school. 
I connected to the database via:

```
hr/password as sysdba;
```

Then I executed the following code in order to show the few default tables that we used to work with in class (jobs, employees, department and similar tables):

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

As a result I got 701 table, many of them have dollar signs, I looked thorouly through the results and found that the tables I need are within the results, such as the table 'COUNTRIES'

However, if I try to do

```
desc countries;
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES;
```

It echoes an "inexistant table" error.

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: try SELECT * FROM database.COUNTRIES;

Comment: @user3091574: didn't change anything.

Comment: database means your database_name in which your table present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the tables you are seeing are system tables that can be used to query meta information about Oracle. Other table probably contain sample data.

The error message indicates that the tables are either in a different schema or that you have no right to access them.

If I'm not mistaken, COUNTRIES is a sample table in the HR schema. So if you connect with the HR user, you should be able to access them. Try either to connect as a regular user (without *as sysdba*):

```
hr/password
```

Or put the schmea name in front of the table name:

```
select * from HR.COUNTRIES;
```

BTW: The schema is directly linked to the user. Therefore user and schema is more or less the same and it is often called *owner* as well, e.g. in  DBA_TABLES.

If you have insufficient rights, then you would need to grant it (using the SYSDBA user):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON HR.COUNTRIES TO ABDEL;
```

(ABDEL or whatever your username is.)

Comment: Putting the schema name in front of the table name does the trick; connecting with user/pw solely without sysdba returns an "account locked" error.

Comment: As SYSDBA, you can unlock the account: `ALTER USER HR ACCOUNT UNLOCK`.